# Why is an anonymous class in a static context valid

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have a misunderstanding about what an anonymous class in Java is. Consider the following simple example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    B b = new B(){ };
    System.out.println(b.b);
}

interface B{ int b = 1; }
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/4j0rfe)**

Why does the code compile? The [JLS, chapt 15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5) says:

> An anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3); it is never
>   static

But the [JLS, chapt 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly
>   declared static.

So the anonymous class is an inner class. But we use them in the static context. Why is it correct here?

Comment: `B b = new B(){};` is not an anonymous class. And it works because it is *used in* a static context, it is declaring the inner class itself static that is forbidden.

Comment: @Shywim So what type was the object created by `new B(){}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class can be created in a static context without being declared static, and this is what is happening here. Let's look at what being declared static, and created in a static context means:

The difference between an anonymous class created in a static context and a non-static context is whether it has an enclosing instance:

> If C is an anonymous class, then:
>
> - If the class instance creation expression occurs in a static context, then i has no immediately enclosing instance.
> - Otherwise, the immediately enclosing instance of i is this.

A nested class that is declared static allows static members:

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.
>
> A nested class that is not an inner class may declare static members
> freely, in accordance with the usual rules of the Java programming
> language.

By saying a nested class that is 'implicity declared static', it refers to things like classes within interfaces:

> A member class of an interface is implicitly static (§9.5) so is never
> considered to be an inner class.

Anonymous classes are not declared static (neither explicitly with a keyword, or implicitly such as being inside an interface), and so do not allow the declaration of static members. They can however be created within a static context, which means that they don't refer to an enclosing instance.

Because the anonymous classes are not declared static, both quotes in the question are consistent.

Answer (score 3):

You should differentiate between anonymous and inner classes

With this statement you create a class implementing the interface B. The class has no name so it's called an anonymous class. The `javac` compile will create a class file with following naming rule YourClass$1.class (where 1 is a sequential number, based on the number of anonymous classes in YourClass.

```
B b = new B(){ };
```

The class created by `new B(){ }` cannot be declared as static. ("An anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3); it is never static").

A static nested class example

```
class YourClass {
    static class StaticNestedClass {
    }
}
```

A non-static nested class example

```
class YourClass {
    // An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.
    class InnerClass {
    }
}
```

There are two types of nested classes: static and non-static. Nested classes which are declared static are so-called `static nested classes`, whereas nested classes not declared as static are so-called `inner classes`.

Comment: We are looking for answers citing the JLS instead of from your understanding.

Comment: This is a basic introduction to inner classes but doesn't address the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

B is an inner **interface**. As such B is implicitely static and you can reference B in a static context.
(From JLS 8.5.1 : *A member interface is implicitly static (§9.1.1).*)

But the anonymous class created through B is not static, and if referenced from a non static context, you could get access to the outer object :

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        B b = new B() {

            @Override
            public Ess3 getParent() {
                //return Ess3.this;  ERROR : non static variable cannot be referenced from static context
                return null;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(b.b);
    }

    interface B {

        int b = 1;
        Ess3 getParent();
    }

    /* a non static method */
    void foo() {
        B b = new B() {

            @Override
            public Ess3 getParent() {
                return Ess3.this; // this anonymous class is not static
            }

        };

    }
}
```

In your example, you could think you created an static anonymous inner class, because you created it :

- from a static nested interface
- in a static context - so with no access to the outer object

But same declaration in a non static context proves that a static nested interface creates a non static anonymous class

Comment: Please cite from JLS to strengthen your claim.

Comment: @nhahtdh : I thought OP already cited the relevant part of JLS but I read it in another answer. Post edited