# Is there anything wrong with static field initialised with anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, inner-classes

I found this code in old legacy system and I don't want to touch it, if there is nothing wrong with it.

But I feel like this code has some flaw and I can't locate it. Is this just not common pattern or there is some hidden pitfalls or memory leaks?

```
private static final Foo action =  new Foo() {

    @Override
    public void onAction(MyDialogFragment fragment) {
        if (fragment.getContext() != null) {
            fragment.getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
};
```

This code is used in a fragment

UPDATE:
I suspect that an object of anonymous inner class has a reference to a parent fragment and since an object of this class saved in static field, it will never be collected, so parent fragment will never be collected too. Are my reasonings wrong?

Comment: I'd probably use `Consumer<MyDialogFragment> consumer = frag -> {};`. I'd also question whether this needs to be `static`.

Comment: This static keyword worry me the most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best explanation is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739694/5868421

Anonymous class in static context don't hold a reference to outer object.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the approach, since the logic deals only with the values passed as parameters. Using a static simply avoids creating multiple instances of the Foo class.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that an object of anonymous inner class has a reference to a parent fragment and since an object of this class saved in static field, it will never be collected, so parent fragment will never be collected too. Are my reasonings wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. It's better to get the fragment like this:

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = MyDialogFragment.instance();
fragment.setNavigator(this);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_myDialog_layout, fragment).commit();
```

There is a better way. You can create 3 classes and an interface which will be implemented by the 3 classes. Activity, Fragment and Presenter. The interface will be Contracts. This is more advanced.

Comment: Sure I can, but I found this in legacy system and I don't want to touch it if there is nothing wrong here. If you could explain what is the problem with this approach, please do.

Comment: If it is in legacy system it's normal.